# How do you place an iOS app distribution link into an email in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

We want to send someone a link to install a development build of an iOS app. The link has to be in the following format:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://our.server/app.plist
```

When I create a new hyperlink in an Outlook email, it will be automatically adjusted to:

```
itms-services:///?action=download-manifest&url=https:/our.server/app.plist
```

One of the `/` was moved. Now, when the users opens that link, he will still be directed to the app download, but the name of the app won't be displayed in the iOS UI. Instead it will display

> {0} wants to install an application

Where `{0}` should have been the name of our app.

How can I get the working link into Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit hacky, but if you cannot stop Outlook from doing this (and with 2003, I can't either) then you could always set up a redirect on a server you own (which goes to the correct iTunes link) and then send the recipient the link to the redirect in the email instead.

If you're not too security averse, then you could always try creating the redirect in [bit.ly](https://bitly.com/) - although I don't know whether or not they'll allow the `itms-services` protocol handler.

**[EDIT]** As pointed out by Oliver in the comments, bit.ly doesn't like that protocol handler - however other redirection services might be more forgiving.

Comment: Yeah, that works great. I took [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5411601/259953) (but removed the JS code). The `meta` refresh actually works great in Safari on iOS and when you visit the website you get the popup that asks about installation. I didn't use the JS as it didn't play well when I opened the page on my desktop.

Comment: `bit.ly` doesn't like the protocol btw.